# Grid won't rotate

Tags: wpf, xaml

WPF Newbie Problem:

I am trying to rotate a grid in a storyboard in a visualstatemanager, but nothing happens.  I have pared down my project to the simple sample below, and still no luck.  The opacity animation works fine, but the grid doesn't rotate.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

XAML:

```
Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="gridMain">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup Name="vsgOrientation">
            <VisualState x:Name="vsHorizontal"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="vsVertical">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation To="90" Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName ="gridTest" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation To="0.25" Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName ="gridTest" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid x:Name="gridTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="159,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" Background="#FFB85E5E"/>
</Grid>
```

And this code behind:

```
Class MainWindow 

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(gridMain, vsVertical.Name, False)

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you are missing the RenderTransform on your Grid. The default `RenderTransform` is `Transform.Identity` and your animation cannot find the `RotateTransform` to animate so nothing happens. Try this:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="159,108,0,0" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" Background="#FFB85E5E">
   <Grid.RenderTransform>
      <RotateTransform/>
   </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

EDIT:
If you want to do multiple transforms then you'll need to add a `TransformGroup`

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
   <TransformGroup>
     <ScaleTransform/>
     <SkewTransform/>
     <RotateTransform/>
     <TranslateTransform/>
   </TransformGroup>
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

Keep what you need and remove those that you don't. Then update your `Storyboard.TargetProperty` to use the new TransformGroup.

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
```

Where the `2` in `(TransformGroup.Children)[2]` is the index of the Transform you want to animate.

Comment: Thanks, I found another post that led me to the same place.  Unfortunately it makes no difference.

Comment: +1 since the RenderTransform is indeed missing, now @2stroke change your TargetProperty to Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" and change RotateTransform to CompositeTransform and should work, will test later if not this is a shot just at glancing.

Comment: @ChrisW. There is a CompositeTransform in Silverlight, but not in WPF. `(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)` or shorter, `RenderTransform.Angle` is the correct property path.

Comment: @Clemens ah crap you're right, I forget to pay attention to the nuance's sometimes. In that case when I get a free minute later I'll have to load up his example and take a closer look. Cheers

Comment: Thanks.  Apparently CompositeTransform is only a Silverlight construct, so no joy.

Comment: @ChrisW. Well, I already did that and found that this answer solves the problem.

Comment: I got it working by putting the grid on a canvas, and rotating the canvas (in conjunction with the <RotateTransform/> suggestion here). I'd love to know why the grid by itself doesn't work.

Comment: Stuck again.  The second I place <RotateTransform/> into a <TransformGroup> it stops working.  I am trying to rotate and translate in the same storyboard.

Comment: I've added how to work with TransformGroups to my answer